# Visualise Workflow Diagram from plain text

Tags: version-control, workflow, plaintext

Assuming there is a plain text with description of the workflow (Just plain English in some predefined format).

Are there any tools (better online) to visualize the flow based on a plain text?

What for: to store the description of the workflow in a source control system and be able to quickly remember/understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I find the idea appealing but doubt it could be practical. You mention "plain text" but not sure if this means source code or a natural language description.

If it is source code maybe you can find something that automatically generates flowcharts from a specific language (you could have better luck if you stated what the language is).

If you are trying to extract a flowchart from a high-level English (or whatever) language descriptions I think it will prove quite a challenge.

If I had to do this, I'd go with Perl starting by https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Flowchart::Script for the "rendering" while reading a bit on NLP for the parsing (ex.: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=41281).